# ELSD detection principle

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

While documenting myself on the detectors used in HPLC, I came across one that I did not know: ELSD.

I understood that the sample with the mobile phase was nebulized at the column outlet but I do not understand what is measured next.

Could you clarify this for me?

Comment: Was this link not successful in explaining ? [Evaporative light scattering detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_light_scattering_detector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ELSD is an acronym for Evaporative Light Scattering Detector. It is used as a quasi-universal detector for HPLC.

The first step is the nebulization of the column effluents with a dry gas as you have mentioned. If the column effluents contain any **non-volatile** analyte, then those will form minute particles. The mintue particles become suspended in the gas stream and form an aerosol. The gas stream is made to pass through a focused light beam (usually a diode laser) which is perpendicular to the flow direction.

If aersol is present, the light will be scattered, and can be detected/analysed by a detector photodiode which is placed perpendicular to both the light beam and flow direction.

There is a nice picture that I got from [this](https://www.ssi.shimadzu.com/products/liquid-chromatography/detector-elsd-lt-III.html) site:

[image: ELSD detector internal workings]

---

Reference- Analytical Chemistry, G. D. Christian, P. K. Dasgupta, K. A. Schug, 7th ed., Wiley, 2013

Comment: Nice explanation, the key point is that the analyte has to *relatively* non-volatile with respect to the mobile phase.